# ASHX File Download Corrupted File

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, handler, ashx

When ever I access my ashx eg download.ashx?id=18 it gets the file, but then when the save dialog pops up it wants me to save download.ashx rather than the file I have stored in the Database (lets say mypdf.pdf) If you open the file download it opens in Visual Studio and doesnt really show anything useful. What is causing this, I have tried it in many browsers and many machines and it all does the same?

Thanks

```
        string id = ctx.Request.QueryString["id"];
        string name = null;
        string mime = null;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONN);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DownloadActivityFile", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aid", id);

        byte[] afile = null;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                mime = reader["ActivityFileMIME"].ToString();
                ctx.Response.ContentType = mime;
                afile = (byte[])reader["ActivityFile"];
                name = reader["ActivityFileName"].ToString();
            }
            ctx.Response.Buffer = false;
            ctx.Response.ContentType = mime;
            ctx.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; {0}", name));
            ctx.Response.Clear();
            ctx.Response.BinaryWrite(afile);
            ctx.Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ctx.Response.Write(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{0}\"` header.
Note **`filename=`**, and the quotes around the name.

Comment: The quotes are optional, it seems; even the [rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) has examples like `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=genome.jpeg;
          modification-date="Wed, 12 Feb 1997 16:29:51 -0500";`

Comment: @Marc: Until you put a space in the filename.  http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download